# AKS public ip not accessible

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes

I have below config in my ingress service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: **.***.**.***
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
```

we have purchased this public ip from azure. If we remove this loadBalancerIP from service yaml and deploy and then use the ip listed by `kubectl get services -n nginx-ingress`, It works fine when we access the service end points. But with this public ip nothing seems to be working.

Please find below service description (`kubectl describe service nginx-ingress -n nginx-ingress-os`):

```
[openapianil@LHGOPENAPIDEV001 github]$ kubectl describe service nginx-ingress -n nginx-ingress-os
Name:                     nginx-ingress
Namespace:                nginx-ingress-os
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"nginx-ingress","namespace":"nginx-ingress-os"},"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy"...
Selector:                 app=nginx-ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.0.44
IP:                       **.**.**.***
LoadBalancer Ingress:     **.**.**.***
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31247/TCP
Endpoints:                **.**.**.***:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32241/TCP
Endpoints:                **.**.**.***:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30880
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  1m    service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   43s   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

Please help!!

Comment: After you specify the public IP address, does this service deploy successfully? could you please run this command `kubectl describe service nginx-ingress` and post that output in your question?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Updated my problem statement with the same. please help.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, after AKS created complete, Azure will create two resource groups.

If you want to create service with IP address, you should create static IP address in another resource group, name like `MC_myResourceGRoup_myAKSCluster_eastus`.

You can use Azure CLI command to create public IP address:

```
az network public-ip create --resource-group MC_myResourceGRoup_myAKSCluster_eastus --name myAKSPublicIP --allocation-method static
```

Also you can use Azure portal to create it, but you **can't** add DNS to it.

Then you can use static IP address like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 52.224.235.119
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-front1
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**Note:**

1.Create Azure public IP address **without** DNS name.
2.Create Azure public IP address in this resource group `MC_myResourceGRoup_myAKSCluster_eastus`.
3.You can use `kubectl describe service` to check the status, like this:

```
[root@jasoncli@jasonye jason]# kubectl describe service azure-vote-front1
Name:                     azure-vote-front1
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=azure-vote-front1
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.76.241
IP:                       52.224.235.119
LoadBalancer Ingress:     52.224.235.119
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30416/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.11:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  CreatingLoadBalancer  45m   service-controller  Creating load balancer
  Normal  CreatedLoadBalancer   44m   service-controller  Created load balancer
```

**Update:**

Here is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-back
        image: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-back
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-back
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-front
image: microsoft/azure-vote-front:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: "azure-vote-back"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: 40.71.3.119
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-front
```

Comment: if we look at above example, once its in above state we should be ale to `telenet 52.224.235.119 80` right? and it should get connected message. But in my case even after successful deployment it still keeps trying to connect. Any idea?

Comment: One more query on the same. Can we have other services to on the same load balancer ip (hope its a yes with different port may be).

Comment: @AnilKumarP Sorry for the delay, Azure does not support one IP address for multiple services. I test it in my lab, get this error message: `Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="PublicIPReferencedByMultipleIPConfigs"` and `Message="Public ip address /subscriptions/b834c23f/resourceGroups/MC_jasonakss_jasonakss_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/jasonip1 is referenced by multiple ipconfigs in resource /subscriptions/b74c23f/resourceGroups/MC_jasonakss_jasonakss_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes."`

Comment: @AnilKumarP By the way, does the static IP address work for you? I have update my yaml to answer, please check it, if you need more help, please let me know. Sorry for the delay:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I had configured one the apis to public ip, it was working fine. What i am trying to do now is have this public ip configured as a loadBalancerIP for my NGINX Server which runs on 2 ports 80 and 443 http/https respectively. This is not working at all. By the way how did you identify this error? where it throws PublicIPReferencedByMultipleIPConfigs?

Comment: @AnilKumarP I check it via `kubectl describe service servicename` .

Comment: Okay I had got 2 services deployed actually, one of other was NGINX server. It was not showing any errors as such when i described the service as above. Also do happen to have any idea on NGINX ?

Comment: What's your mean about "have any idea on NGINX"?

Comment: NGINX is a loadbalancer that can be used as a ingress controller for the ingress types we deploy in kubernetes. So i wanted to check if you are aware of nginx so that i can ask nginx issue thats happening on this public ip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165613/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-anil-kumar-p).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when working through the [QuickStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal)  The EXTERNAL-IP was listed as localhost if I didn't enable RBAC when created the AKS.  Worked as expected when RBAC was enabled for me.